# Extract null value count effeciently from a groupBy relational dataset

Tags: scala, apache-spark

My group by code gives me the following result

```
  var datasets = dataset.select(col(x._1)).repartition(32).groupBy(col(x._1)).count.orderBy($"count".desc)

+------------------------+-----+
|Source                  |count|
+------------------------+-----+
|    Application         | 7167|
|                    null|    2|
|                      No|    1|
|                  Closed|    1|
+------------------------+-----+
```

How do we extract the number of "null" from this dataframe ?

So far i have reached

```
var nulls =  datasets.filter(datasets.col(x._1).isNull).select($"count").head()(1).getOrElse(0)
```

I need to get this to float

Tricky part is that sometimes the result of nulls is empty and code should not error out

```
 error: value getOrElse is not a member of Any
         var nulls = datasets.filter(datasets.col(x._1).isNull).head()(1).getOrElse(0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is safe, even if `null`does not appear:

```
var nulls = datasets.filter(datasets.col(x._1).isNull).select($"count").as[Long].collect().headOption.map(_.toFloat).getOrElse(0.0)
```